# How do I repair this interior door?

Tags: doors, door-frame

I am trying to fix a door that the kids broke.  Should I use use wood glue, clamps, and some small nails?

[image]

Comment: While waiting for the answer, I ended up applying wood glue and clamping on the door surfaces directly since I had four bar clamps with me.  The repair seems to be holding up, as wood glue is fairly strong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try applying some wood glue  into the split with a small brush. Sandwich the door between two 2x4's with some clamps. It may help to put some wax paper on the 2x4 to keep any glue from adhering the board to the door. Tighten the clamps until the glue starts to squeeze from the crack. Let it sit 24 hours, remove the clamps and scrape any excess dried glue. Repaint to hide the repair.

Comment: One thing I would add: test the clamps and 2x4s without glue first to make sure there are no splinters of wood that will prevent it clamping flat. If so, clean them out with a thin putty knife or similar tool.

Comment: I'd give consideration to replacing what appears to be an inexpensive well used hollowcore door, particularly if wood clamps, glue, and loose lumber were not already on hand.